# What will perform better?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database-design

I do have 'topics',  each 'topic'  has 'questions'. Both, topics and questions,  have 'statistics'  that will be updated at every use.

Should I create 'questions'  as a subfield of  'topic' documents? Or I must create a collection named 'questions'  and relate it to 'topic'  using sort of a foreign key?

Further,  using the independent 'questions' collections will make it 'harder/expensive' to list all the questions related with a topic?

I'm so noob

Comment: You may want to be a bit more specific on what you mean by "perform better". Performance will be dependent on what you plan to be doing with the data (will you be updating them alot? mostly reading them? a bit of both?). Also, will there be a case where you want to access the question directly? How are you storing the statistics?

Comment: Hi Ting Sun,  each time a 'question'  gets published its statistics fields get updated. The 'topic' statistics,  but,  are getting updated too.  Example: How many ears do cats have?  Publishing this question means updating the question statistics fields but also the 'cats'  topic statistics fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer this the best I can, but you will probably want to do some testing on your side to make sure it actually works better.

If you aren't expecting each topic to have an insanely large amount of questions, you can technically just include them as an array in the 'topic' document. This makes querying for a set of questions for a specific topic much easier and probably faster than if questions and topics were its own collections.

However there is a huge drawback to doing this. Say you want to access something specific about a specific question. In order to find that question, you will need to know which topic it belongs to, query for that specific topic, loop through all the questions in that topic to find the one that matches and then return the requested info. Alternatively you can keep track of the index of the question within the array in topics for a bit quicker access, but that means to access any questions you will have to keep track of 2 different indexes. Same goes for if you want to update anything for a specific question.

Storing questions and topics as their own collection (use a shared key like topicID) will make it easier for you to access/update anything specific for both questions and topics.

Now about performance when accessing questions. This will depend on how you load your data. If your application usually only loads 1 topic + related questions at a time, you will theoretically be making 2 queries if you have separate collections, 1 query if you have questions nested in topics. If you want to access a specific question, having separate collections will be faster. So it all  boils down to which operation will happen the most.

Remember that proper indexing will help read times and unless you have an insanely large dataset with a ton of users accessing it, the marginal gain in read time by nesting questions in topics is probably not worth it.

Comment: Finally I decided to store the questions within the topic document. I did in this way because they mainly appear grouped by topic. Not sure, but, if updating the statistics of all the questions will be a slow task